# Jenkins unable to fetch repo - code 255 permission denied

Tags: git, github, jenkins

I'm trying to set up Jenkins to work with git webhooks. So far I have

- Jenkins running
- Created an ssh key pair under the `jenkins` user
- Added the key to git deploy keys
- Added the git plugin
- Configured the project to use git with the repo
- Set the branch to `*/develop` to only watch the dev branch
- Set the custom workspace directory to `/data/www/<site>`
- Added the `ubunutu` group to the `jenkins` user (see below)

And when trying to build the project, I get this error:

```
Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace /data/www/<site>
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.jenkins.url git@github.com:<repo_url> # timeout=10
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'jenkins'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from git@github.com:<repo_url>
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:735)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:983)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1016)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:485)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1276)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:610)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:532)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1744)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:374)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git config remote.jenkins.url git@github.com:<repo_url>" returned status code 255:
stdout: 
stderr: error: could not lock config file .git/config: Permission denied

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1591)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1567)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1563)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommand(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1249)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommand(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1261)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.setRemoteUrl(CliGitAPIImpl.java:961)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.setRemoteUrl(GitAPI.java:160)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:723)
    ... 11 more
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'jenkins'
```

The repo has already been pulled by a different user (in this case, `ubuntu:ubuntu`) in the `/data/www/<site>` directory, so initially I thought adding the `ubunutu` group to `jenkins` would fix the problem, but no luck. I've also tried logging in as the `jenkins` user and pulling the repo, which I can do successfully.

I've tried googling everything I can think of, but most searches point to people who are having key problems, rather than config file permission problems. At this point I'm out of ideas.

Edit:

`ls -la` in the `.git` dir:

```
drwxrwxr-x   2 ubuntu  ubuntu   4096 Mar  5 12:13 branches
-rw-rw-r--   1 ubuntu  ubuntu     15 Mar  5 18:09 COMMIT_EDITMSG
-rw-rw-r--   1 jenkins jenkins   318 Jun  1 14:55 config
-rw-rw-r--   1 ubuntu  ubuntu     73 Mar  5 12:13 description
-rw-rw-r--   1 ubuntu  ubuntu     88 May 29 12:50 FETCH_HEAD
-rw-rw-r--   1 ubuntu  ubuntu     24 May 28 13:21 HEAD
drwxrwxr-x   2 ubuntu  ubuntu   4096 May 28 13:49 hooks
-rw-rw-r--   1 ubuntu  ubuntu  36480 May 29 12:50 index
drwxrwxr-x   2 ubuntu  ubuntu   4096 Mar  5 12:13 info
drwxrwxr-x   3 ubuntu  ubuntu   4096 Mar  5 12:13 logs
drwxrwxr-x 260 ubuntu  ubuntu   4096 Apr 10 10:40 objects
-rw-rw-r--   1 jenkins jenkins    41 May 29 11:53 ORIG_HEAD
-rw-rw-r--   1 ubuntu  ubuntu    179 Mar  5 12:13 packed-refs
drwxrwxr-x   5 ubuntu  ubuntu   4096 Mar  5 12:13 refs
```

`ls -la` from the parent dir (it's a Laravel 5 app):

```
drwxrwxr-x 13 ubuntu   ubuntu    4096 Apr  3 11:07 app
-rwxrwxr-x  1 ubuntu   ubuntu    2452 Mar  5 12:13 artisan
drwxrwxr-x  2 ubuntu   ubuntu    4096 Mar 11 08:18 bootstrap
-rwxrwxr-x  1 ubuntu   ubuntu    1094 Mar 11 08:16 composer.json
-rw-rw-r--  1 ubuntu   ubuntu   79004 Mar 11 08:17 composer.lock
-rwxrwxr-x  1 ubuntu   ubuntu     146 Mar  5 12:13 CONTRIBUTING.md
drwxrwxr-x  8 ubuntu   ubuntu    4096 May  6 09:45 frontend
drwxrwxr-x  8 ubuntu   ubuntu    4096 Jun  1 14:56 .git
-rwxrwxr-x  1 ubuntu   ubuntu      12 Mar  5 12:13 .gitattributes
-rwxrwxr-x  1 ubuntu   ubuntu     160 Mar  5 12:13 .gitignore
-rwxrwxr-x  1 ubuntu   ubuntu     567 Mar  5 12:13 phpunit.xml
drwxrwxr-x  7 www-data www-data  4096 Mar  5 17:13 public
-rwxrwxr-x  1 ubuntu   ubuntu    2051 Mar  5 12:13 readme.md
-rwxrwxr-x  1 ubuntu   ubuntu     519 Mar  5 12:13 server.php
drwxrwxr-x 29 ubuntu   ubuntu    4096 Mar 11 08:18 vendor
```

Groups:

```
$ cat /etc/group | grep jenkins
ubuntu:x:1000:jenkins
jenkins:x:113:

$ cat /etc/group | grep ubuntu
adm:x:4:syslog,ubuntu
dialout:x:20:ubuntu
cdrom:x:24:ubuntu
floppy:x:25:ubuntu
sudo:x:27:ubuntu
audio:x:29:ubuntu
dip:x:30:ubuntu
video:x:44:ubuntu
plugdev:x:46:ubuntu
netdev:x:102:ubuntu
ubuntu:x:1000:jenkins
```

Comment: Have you solved your problem? If so i'll edit my answer so you can accept it

Comment: Have you tried rebooting your server, to ensure that the new group-membership `jenkins` member of `ubuntu` is picked-up?

Comment: We did narrow it down to some kind of permissions issues, but have yet to successfully figure out the exact cause of the problem. For now we're worked around it.

Answer (score 5):

This works pretty nice form me:

1 - Find the git `config.lock` file, inside the **jenkins** folder run:

`find . -type f -name "config.lock"`

2 - Delete the `config.lock` file founded.

Thats it!

Answer (score 2):

Check the owner / permissions of the .git/config file in the jenkins workspace. It's probably still owned by the ubuntu user. Change the owner to the jenkins user.

Comment: It is owned by the ubuntu user, but jenkins is in the ubunutu group which I assumed would be enough? And if it's not, why can I manually pull when logged in as the jenkins user?

Comment: `jenkins` in the `ubuntu` group is OK, provided you have rebooted/restarted.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you've already looked at it but I found [a forum post](http://jenkins-ci.361315.n4.nabble.com/Git-polling-could-not-lock-config-file-git-config-File-exists-td4752086.html) where links were given to tickets. Go through them, you may find something.

Citing :

- [JENKINS-21914](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-21914) - matches your error message, but I can't duplicate it
- [JENKINS-21376](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-21376) - different error message, but related to lock file
- [JENKINS-24179](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-24179) - different error message
- [JENKINS-25353](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-25353) - lingering lock file (not likely related to this one)

More relevent listed errors are :

- `.git\config.lock` needs to be deleted
- Need `git-client-plugin` version 1.6.2 at least

Comment: `git-client-plugin` is at 1.17.1. `config.lock` doesn't exist. The error references just `config`.

Comment: Could you give us the result of ls -la in the .git directory and from its parent directory. And cat /etc/group | grep jenkins and cat /etc/group | grep ubuntu  . I would like to be sure about permission.

Comment: Added all this info to the question.

Comment: Are you sure that Jenkins is running with jenkins user? Odd question I'm sorry, I can't find out why it's not going the right way. This command is clearly local, so it has no link with github and ssh key. I tried several thing and got almost similar error when I had no config file (`error: could not lock config file .git/config: No such file or directory`). The next operation done by Jenkins is `Fetching upstream changes from <repo>`. Some problems may appear there with unknown_host, but if you tried manually you must have accept the host... Check Jenkins user or try full right (just testing)

Comment: I can confirm that it looks like it's using the jenkins user. I created a new item, and the files that item creates show `jenkins:jenkins` as the owner.

Comment: At this point I'm not even sure I'm using Jenkins the way it's supposed to be used, but I'd still like to figure out what the issue is here.

Comment: have you tried to clean the local repo? Maybe just by cleaning all the project directory and let Jenkins pull from scratch

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: I added the dir `mkdir ~/.git` and it fixed the error for me. Ref: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/git-users/pyv6ldFxUio/qV4pvE_z3zwJ

Answer (score 0):

In order to troubleshoot this, you should login as or su to the `jenkins` user (with the assurance that Jenkins is running as `jenkins`), using *the same environment the Jenkins service is running with*, then `cd /data/www/<site>/.git` then `ls -als config.lock` and `touch config.lock`.  This is the file Git is having trouble creating - these commands will check whether it already exists, and if not, whether the `jenkins` user can create it.

As unlikely as it seems, the most likely problem is that you need to restart some things or reboot, because [new group-membership permissions are not applied to existing processes or their children](https://superuser.com/a/168429/216364).  Have you restarted Jenkins?  If not, stop Jenkins, and depending on how it is launched - you need a fresh shell - relaunch it  Reboot the server if you need to be really sure.

Also please report your filesystem type and mount options.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in rubygems/installer.rb

Use `gem update --system` to update rubygems to lastest stable version that fixes this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same issue after `Jenkins` machine got restarted, fixed it updating the credentials for proxy in `.gitconfig` along with **deleting the job folder from Jenkins workspace**, as follows:

```
$ cat ~/.gitconfig
```

Updating below as:

```
[http]
        proxy = http://username:updated-password@proxy.myserver.com:80
        sslverify = false
[https]
        proxy = http://username:updated-password@proxy.myserver.com:80
        sslverify = false
[url "http://github.com/"]
        insteadOf = git://github.com/

[user]
        name = Arpit Aggarwal
        email = arpit.aggarwal@xebia.com
[core]
        autocrlf = true
        excludesfile = C:\\Data\\gitignore_global.txt
```